# User information changing for online school site only

Tags: virus, antimalware

My son goes to online school. Our user name, password, email and security question keeps changing. Tech support is saying I have a hacker in my network. I have checked and changed all passwords for the router and changed internet providers. Running malware and antivirus and nothing found. Only happening on school site. Running windows 7 and 10. What else can be done?

Comment: Usernames typically don't change. The fact that you think the username is changing, could mean you are logging in as a *different* user and then of course you would have a different password, email, and security question. What is making you believe that the username is changing?

Comment: I have to call customer service to get the user name and password.

Comment: Are they perhaps cancelling your account for some reason? Does progress save between accounts? That's the only reason I can think of for a username to change.

Comment: If they have reason to believe this is the case then they should be able to provide you with the IP address used to modify the account (although this might be a single addres shared by your network) the user agent and the time the changes were applied. If they cannot supply this information it would rather suggest that they are merely trying to fob you off / transfer blame? OTOH this should allow you to focus your investigation / amend your logging.

Answer (score 2):

Who has access to the change process screen? It would be a very unusual type of activity for a hacker - there is no benefit to them. Also, it's very rare that a username or email address would be changed by an organisation without a specific request.

The only person this would seem to affect in day-to-day operation is your son, so it may be worth checking if he has seen any other suspicious activity whilst logged on - maybe try sitting with him for a few days so he can point out any issues as they occur, which would give a much better idea of what is going on.

The general process in a business context would be to consider who has access to reset this information, and ensure that only people who need to be able to change it have that kind of access - there may be a restricted access account that doesn't allow these changes to be made, which might be suitable for day to day use, with a strong password set for the account with permissions to make these changes kept in a safe place (locked safe, wallet, etc). This should be tamper evident, so that any access to this can be discovered, should any changes happen. If this has not been accessed, and a sufficiently strong password was used, it strongly suggests that the problem is with the provider.

Comment: I have sat with him and recorded him without his knowledge. He doesn't know my user name and password. I can change this information once I log in and tech support can change this information. I have had administration at the school make user name and passwords and not give them to us and it still changed. No one has an answer for why this is happening. It has been off and on for over an year now. The longest we can go is two weeks without it changing.

Comment: I'd suggest that this is a problem with their systems, rather than yours in that case - if details are changing when you have no access to them, it's not down to activity on your network. After a year of this, I'd be inclined to look for a more security conscious provider, since I'm guessing that these accounts will have some kind of payment information linked.